# Call function in main

Tags: function, kotlin, program-entry-point

How to call this function in main? 
I've tried change this function to static, but companion object doesn't see repo, what is necessary to save object in database..

```
class ExcelReader (val repo: SomeRepository){

 fun readFromExcel(filepath: String) {}
```

Comment: From which main, Java or Kotlin? Where is the companion object? What is ExcelReader? Which object to what database? Please, create and [mcve] and [edit] your question to be more clear as currently there is no way to properly answer/understand your problem

Answer (score 1):

The code example in the question is incomplete, but I suppose `readFromExcel` is a member function of `ExcelReader` class. To call it from `main` you need first to construct an instance of `ExcelReader` and then invoke the function on that instance:

```
fun main() {
    val repo = TODO("Obtain repository somehow")
    val reader = ExcelReader(repo)

    reader.readFromExcel("myfile.xls")
}
```